# Use the central limit theorem to prove that...

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm stuck on a problem I'm really hoping you could help me with.

Basically, I need to use the central limit theorem to prove that:

$\frac{X_n-\frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{n}/2} \rightarrow N(0,1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I've figured out that this $X_n$ is a series of Bernoulli random variables, but I have no idea how to approach this any closer.

Comment: What is $X_n$ ?

Comment: I think that in order for this to work $X_n$ is a Bernoulli series, which is also side mentioned in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $X_n\sim b\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right)$, right? Then, you can consider $X_n$ as the sum of iid $Y_i\sim Be\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ ($Be$ stands for bernoulli), then, since $E(X_n)=\frac{n}{2}$ and $var(X_n)=\frac{n}{4}$, hence by CLT, it is proved